# How to not evaluate query until certain point? (to have Relation object inspect)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider this:

```
1] pry(main)> User.joins(:tasks)
=> #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fe8923d31cc>
[2] pry(main)> User.where(state: 'undefined')
  User Load (6.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."state" = 'undefined'
=> []
```

So in first case it returns Relation object, what is "lazy" - I can apply other methods to it (like `.where`), and it doesn't fire query itself.

But `where` does the opposite thing - it immediately proceeds query. But what if I want to have here also active record relation, so I can chain other scopes to it, and then evaluate query?

I want to have query in separate method and then to apply to return of this method `find_each`.

Comment: Interesting.  Do yo have the same problem if you assign the relation to a variable?  `undefined_users = User.where(state: 'undefined')`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, still evaluates, but may it occur just in rails console? (development env)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm wondering.  I use chained "where" clauses a lot... "@users = User.where..."  then "@users = @users.where..." then "@users = @users.where..." and the SQL is never executed until I finally access the returned data via an enumerator (like `each`) or a `count` or `pluck` method.

Answer (score 1):

Using `where(...)` is returning an `ActiveRecord_Relation`.

Try calling `.class` on the end of that line like so:
`User.where(state: 'undefined').class` and see what you get.

What you are seeing is simply the console calling something like `.inspect` on the relation.

Outside of the console, ActiveRecord Relations will lazily evaluate and not make a call to the DB until absolutely necessary.

See this post from the Odin Project for a fuller explanation:

https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/active-record-queries